# Justification for a real number to a complex power

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I searched extensively online and found that everyone would agree with the following:

$2^i = e^{\log{2^i}} = e^{i*\log{2}}$. About the second equality (taking the $i$ out of the $\log$), it seems natural. But I cannot justify this myself.

I understand that, $\log(z1*z2) = \log(z1)+\log(z2)$, and therefore, if I have something like $\log(i^2)$, then it's just $\log(i*i) = \log(i) + \log(i) = 2\log(i)$, but this is because we have a rational exponent. How can I do the similar thing for $2^i$? Or is there some other way to justify the step pulling the $i$ out of the $log$?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is $\log(2^i)=i\log(2)? $

Let $x= \log(2^i)$

Then by definition $e^x=2^i$ but indeed this is an infinite set of numbers in the complex plane with this property and $y=i\log(2)$ is one such element that has this property  because 
$e^y=e^{i \log(2)}=(e^{\log(2)})^{i}=2^i$

As is commented below and in the answer by Santos: we will need to decide exactly how to extend $\log$ to the complex plane to make any progress here.

Comment: I thought this puzzle was easier than I thought at first and has something to do with how we extend log to the complex plane. There are indeed a few $x \in \mathbb{C}$ that have this property that $e^x=2^i$ because of the way the complex plane works. So we need to make some choices about how we want to extend $\log$. I will let some answerer take it from there lest I steer us the wrong direction.

Comment: In fact complex exponentiation (power) and log are quite complicated. They are "multivalued" functions and you have to choose a branch of them to be able and invert. In this example $2^i=2^i e*{i2k\pi}$: just the principal branch of the log is $i*ln2$.

Comment: Who would have thunk it! Extending things to the complex plane makes them more ... complex. Thanks.

Comment: ..luckily not always: actually many operations and concepts become easier in the complex field!

Answer (score 1):

*By definition*, if $a>0$, then $a^z=e^{z\times\log a}$. In particular, $2^i=e^{i\times\log2}$.

Of course, here $\log a$ is the only real logarithm of $a$. In general, a non-zero complex number has infinitely many logarithms, and therefore you shouldn't mention $\log z$ unless you state clearly which logarithm you have in mind. In particular, the equality $\log(z_1z_2)=\log(z_1)+\log(z_2)$ does't make sense in general.